# Only load a module if Flash is detected

Tags: drupal, flash

I am running a Drupal site with Magic Touch as the primary image viewer, unfortunately Magic Touch is built in flash. I need a non-flash fallback image viewer for mobile devices. Any suggestions here would be helpful but I think I may have found the simplest angle. Magic Touch will override any other image viewers that are enabled, so I figured I can enable my fallback image viewer, and I just need a way to disable the Magic Touch module if Flash is not detected or if the user agent is detected as a mobile device.

I've already written a conditional statement with browscap to detect if the user is using a mobile device. Now I just need a function to disable or enable a module conditionally.

Comment: I'd suggesting finding a way to to override page callback if flash is not detected. 
Disabling a module is site-wide change. 
Some user can disable Magic Touch functionality in whole site just by visiting your site in a mobile ?

Comment: I guess I hadn't thought of the load it might put on the server.  I dont know where I would even start with a page callback, I guess it could direct the user to a different template, but I still don't how I would use that to change the image viewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the [module_disable()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_disable/7) or [module_enable()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_enable/7) functions to accomplish these tasks.

Comment: I did start looking into these functions.  So would it be `$disabledmodules = array('magictouch'); module_disable($disabledmodules, $disable_dependents = TRUE);`

Comment: yea, i should think so, please select if this answers your question

Comment: I believe you are right ceejay, which means this is NOT a viable solution for this problem, but those functions will certainly enable or disable the module